# MySQL Delete Rows Based Upon Max Value of Column

Tags: mysql, database, sql-delete

I have a table ('conditions') that contains a column titled "Date"  I would like to delete all of the rows that are not equal to the current date (as determined by the max value of `date(MAX(DATE))`.  Partial table result:

```
| Date     | Time  | Observed                     | Temp | HeatIndex | WindChill | RelHumidity | Wind
| 14-06-21 | 19:30 | Scattered Clouds             | 85.9 | 91        | NA        | 61%         |    2 |
| 14-06-21 | 20:30 | Clear                        | 83.2 | 88        | NA        | 67%         |    3 |
| 14-06-21 | 21:30 | Clear                        | 80.7 | 85        | NA        | 74%         |    5 |
| 14-06-21 | 22:30 | Clear                        | 79.5 | 83        | NA        | 76%         |    4 |
| 14-06-21 | 23:30 | Clear                        | 78.4 | 81        | NA        | 79%         |    4 |
| 14-06-22 | 00:30 | Clear                        | 77.6 | NA        | NA        | 82%         |    3 |
| 14-06-22 | 01:30 | Clear                        | 77.1 | NA        | NA        | 83%         |    3 |
| 14-06-22 | 02:30 | Scattered Clouds             | 77.3 | NA        | NA        | 84%         |    2 |
| 14-06-22 | 03:30 | Clear                        | 77.1 | NA        | NA        | 83%         |    2 |
| 14-06-22 | 04:30 | Clear                        | 76.6 | NA        | NA        | 86%         |    4 |
```

So after the command, I would like to see the following only:

```
| 14-06-22 | 00:30 | Clear                        | 77.6 | NA        | NA        | 82%         |    3 |
| 14-06-22 | 01:30 | Clear                        | 77.1 | NA        | NA        | 83%         |    3 |
| 14-06-22 | 02:30 | Scattered Clouds             | 77.3 | NA        | NA        | 84%         |    2 |
| 14-06-22 | 03:30 | Clear                        | 77.1 | NA        | NA        | 83%         |    2 |
| 14-06-22 | 04:30 | Clear                        | 76.6 | NA        | NA        | 86%         |    4 |
```

I tried:

```
DELETE FROM conditions WHERE Date <> MAX(Date);
```

but received:

```
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
```

The last row will always be the current date.  I have considered adding an ID column and sorting by `DESC`, but I want the last row to be the most recent entry. Every time I insert data (python) into the database, this script containing the `Delete` will be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you can't use MAX for the same reason you can't sub-query the current table on a delete.

What you can do is use `CURDATE()`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate

`DELETE FROM conditions WHERE Date <> CURDATE();`

Comment: This won't work unless `MAX(date) == CURDATE()`, which is not always true (for instance if the last row was created yesterday).

Comment: @julienc The last row will have been created just before the DELETE is run. I assume OP knows that this means he will have 1 row at the beginning of every day. If that becomes a problem, the posted link should get him to a query that clears the past 24h.

Comment: Yes.  1 row after first run of the new day is acceptable.  This is just to keep the DB from growing too large.  I guess that technically, I only need that one row for my application, but its nice to look back throughout the day :)  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The standard SQL for this would be:

```
DELETE
    FROM conditions
    WHERE Date < (select MAX(Date) from conditions)
```

However, MySQL doesn't like it when you use the same table in the `where` clause as you are deleting from.  So instead use a join:

```
delete c
    from conditions c join
         (select max(date) as maxdate from conditions) x
         on c.date < x.maxdate;
```